# Multiply a number by previous cell and different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to know if it is possible to multiply column(A) by column(B) and then keep on multiplying the last column(A) result by column(B), in a fast way instead of doing it manually that is.
For example:

```
A1 = 200
B2 = 0.8
C1 = A1 * B2 = 160 OR C1 = 200 * 0.8 
C2 = C1 * B2 = 128
C3 = C2 * B2 = 102.4
C4 = C3 * B2 = 81.92
```

Etc...

Comment: What do you mean by `A1` `(result)` you stated `A1` = 200. You can't calculate a cell value on a cell value input within the same cell (without use of VBA). Do you accept a result in the column next to it? Also you tag both Excel 2007 and Excel 2010. Which one? Would in `C1` `=A1*$B$2` and in `C2` `=C1*$B$2` copied down do?

Comment: I agree with P.B. in that it's not clear exactly what you're going for (though I took a guess). Try to use [mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for clarity of what your sheet should look like.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I hope it is more clear now. and I am using Excel 2016 it simply forced me to choose 5 tags so I simply tagged only excel tags thank you for editing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
=SCAN(200,SEQUENCE(4),LAMBDA(a,b,a*0.8))
```

Note that you can use references for both `200` and `0.8`.

Comment: Nice. I don't even know what Scan function does. Thanks for upvoting. I did the same.

Comment: I get #NAME? error.. I tried to do
=SCAN(W6,SEQUENCE(4),LAMBDA(v,w,v*V6)) ..
W6 = 200 and V6 = 0.8

Comment: The formula is ms365 based. If you don't have access to these functions you'll receive this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exponents to make the dynamic formula you describe based on the row. So if you put this in cell `A2` and it would do what you describe, and then just drag down:

```
=$A$1*($B$2)^row()
```

Example on [google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MOuI_Pn5cus8t6pd_i3rvWxSeRFbCrpPIDdO4zWk0E0/edit?usp=sharing) (same formula works on Excel).

[image]

Comment: If one would just include `SEQUENCE()` >> `=200*(0.8^SEQUENCE(4))`

Comment: I'm on the discounted version of Excel... not to be too boastful, but we just got vLookup.

Comment: I feel the pain. Anyways, your answer is perfectly fine. Including `SEQUENCE(n)` will just make it spill down 'n' rows so OP wouldn't have to drag. Superior over my answer for sure. `SCAN()` would just make it possible to make any kind of calculation if need be.